# Regex match backslash star

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Can't work this one out, this matches a single star:

```
// Escaped multiply
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("\\*", "g"), '[MULTIPLY]');
```

But I need it to match `\*`, I've tried:

```
\\*
\\\\*
\\\\\*
```

Can't work it out, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close, `\\\\\\*` would have done it.

Better use verbatim strings, that makes it easier:

```
RegExp(@"\\\*", "g")
```

`\\` matches a literal backslash (`\\\\` in a normal string), `\*` matches an asterisk (`\\*` in a normal string).

Answer (score 4):

Remember that there are two 'levels' of escaping.

First, you are escaping your strings for the C# compiler, and you are also escaping your strings for the Regex engine.

If you want to match `"\*"` literally, then you need to escape both of these characters for the regex engine, since otherwise they mean something different. We escape these with backslashes,  so you will have `"\\\*"`.

Then, we have to escape the backslashes in order to write them as a literal string. This means replacing each backslash with two backslashes: `"\\\\\\*"`.

Instead of this last part, we could use a "verbatim string", where no escapes are applied. In this case, you only need the result from the first escaping: `@"\\\*"`.

Comment: @Tim: That matches zero-or-more backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is completely wrong. It looks more like Javascript than C#.

This works fine:

```
string Text = "asdf*sadf";

Text = Regex.Replace(Text, "\\*", "[MULTIPLY]");

Console.WriteLine(Text);
```

Output:

```
asdf[MULTIPLY]sadf
```

To match `\*` you would use the pattern `"\\\\\\*"`.